# How to Query two foreign key, that belong to a table, that has two different relationships

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have been looking, but haven't found the solution.

In my laravel project, I have a table named `players`. Each player has a `position_id` and a `team_id`. Using relationship.

Here are my Models:

---

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Team extends Model
    {
        public function players()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Player');
        }
    }
```

---

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Position extends Model
    {
        public function players()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Player');
        }
    }
```

---

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Player extends Model
{
    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team');
    }
    public function position()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Position');
    }
}
```

---

If I want all players with `position==gk` I make:

```
$players = Position::whereDescription('gk')->players;
```

If I want all player with `team==pac` I make:

```
$players = Team::whereDescription('pac')->players;
```

How do I query, all players from `team==pac` with `position==gk`?

Comment: hi, would you mind to edit your post to includes your models files? without that, we cant identify your db structures

Comment: What Eloquent relations are you using in your `Player` model?

Comment: @Attorn, check my answer. The answer is based on the information you have provided. If it's not enough, provide addtional information and I will try to help you out more.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the responses. I will edit my post, to include my models files. I do not know the team_id number nor the position_id number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Player::where(['position_id'=>$positionId, 'team_id'=>$teamId])->first();
```

or

```
Player::where(['position_id'=>$positionId, 'team_id'=>$teamId])->get();
```

However, this code doesn't take advantage of Eloquent relations and assumes you have already have `$postionId` and `$teamId`.